# Can I template a group of common attributes with Pug?

Tags: pug

I'm setting up templates for HTML emails, and many of my tables look like this:

`table( align='center', border='0', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', width='100%' )`

To save time and improve readability, I thought it would be sweet if I could write something more like this:

```
- var tableAttrs = "align='center', border='0', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', width='100%'"
table( tableAttrs )
```

The above outputs `tableAttrs="tableAttrs"`, or `#{="#{" tableAttrs="tableAttrs" }="}"` if interpolated.

I've also tried a simple mixin which I did not expect to support nesting, and was not disappointed:

```
mixin table()
  table( align='center', border='0', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', width='100%' )

+table()
  tbody...
```

If my goal is possible or not possible, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixins do support nesting if you include a `block` statement.

**Mixin:**

```
mixin table()
  table(align='center', border='0', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', width='100%')
    if block
      block
```

**Usage:**

```
+table()
  tr
    td text
```

**Result:**

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just right, thank you! Did I miss this in the docs or something?